# WordPress sub-menu does not appear correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, wordpress-theming

I would like the sub-menu to appear visible (like a normal sub-menu) instead of hiding under a scroll bar but I have become stuck. I cant get it too appear normally.

http://postimg.org/image/yqe0nz2p7/

```css
    .nav {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    .nav > ul > li {
      margin-right: 55px;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    .nav > ul > li > .sub-menu {
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 0px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-18"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/web-design/">Web Design</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-992" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-992"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/terms/">Terms &#038; Conditions</a> 
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-993" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-993"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/terms/">Terms &#038; Conditions</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-772" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-772"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/search-engine-optimization/">Search Optimization</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-994" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-994"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/terms/">Terms &#038; Conditions</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/price-plans/">Price Plans</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://www.ubietest.ubieportal.co.uk/get-quote/">Get quote</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but here is the secondary nav I'm using right now in my custom WordPress theme built on Bones. This floats right because it's a secondary nav I'm using for social links. In my case I'm using an icon font but the setup is the same I use for primary navigation with sub-menu.

What I do is hide the sub-menu ul using `display:none;` and then when hovering the first `<li>` that changes to `display:block !important;`. In this below example, the `.sN li:hover > ul` CSS is what is making the sub-menu display. I took out the _target blank for you ;)

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="socialNav">

    <ul class="sN">
        <li class="socialOpen"><a href="#">9</a>
            <ul class="socialSub">
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">G</a></li>
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">T</a></li>
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">Y</a></li>
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">V</a></li>
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">P</a></li>
                <li><a class="ss" href="#">Z</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

and here's the CSS (sorry it has much styling):

```
.socialNav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    border: none
}
.sN {
    margin: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px
}
.socialNav ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 0
}
.socialNav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px
}
.socialOpen a {
    display: block;
    font-family: tdp_icons;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-left: 1px solid #555
}
.socialNav ul:hover li a:not(.ss) {
    color: #b13838 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #666
}
.sN li ul {
    border-left: none !important;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    display: none
}
.socialSub { border-radius: 0 0 0 14px }
.socialSub li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #444
}
.socialSub li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 14px
}
.socialSub li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none
}
.socialSub li a {
    font-family: tdp_icons;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    padding: 0;
    color: #444
}
.sN li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto
}
.socialNav ul li a:hover { color: #b13838 }
```

If this is too confusing I can strip out the extra styling when I have time. Sometimes I do use `position:absolute` but in this case I didn't need to because the links are icons and so all the `<ul>` `<li>` and `<a>` tags are the same width.

Hope this helps.